# How to get date given only the day of year number in flutter

Tags: android, ios, date, flutter, calendar

I am fairly new to flutter. In android, I could easily use the `Calendar` class set using `cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, number)` and it will return the `date` for that particular `day_of_year` number. How can I do the same in Flutter.

In Android, this is what I would have done

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,1);  //set date using day of year
return cal.getTime(); //2020-01-01
```

How do I implement this in Flutter.

Comment: try this https://flutterawesome.com/flutter-rounded-date-picker/

Comment: Does this help https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/DateTime-class.html (search dart/dartlang, not flutter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gave this a go for fun, I don't normally do Dart, so apologies if its wrong!

```
var dayOfYear = 1;
var millisInADay = Duration(days: 1).inMilliseconds; // 86400000    
var millisDayOfYear = dayOfYear * millisInADay;
var millisecondsSinceEpoch = DateTime(DateTime.now().year).millisecondsSinceEpoch;

var dayOfYearDate = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(millisecondsSinceEpoch + millisDayOfYear);
```

- For the day of year == 1.
- When there are 86400000 milliseconds in a day.
- Then there are 86400000 millis in that year (1 x 86400000).
- Create a new date for the first day of the year.
- Add the number of millis in the year, to the number of millis to the start of the year since epoch. Create a new date using this milliseconds since epoch.

Reference:

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/DateTime-class.html

Comment: thanks very much, it worked. Interestingly, dayOfYear is 0 for January 1 in Dart. So my first day_of_year is 0. thanks