# DateTime fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch returning Incorrect Values

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime

So, I'm working on a converter for changing JDE Julian Dates to Gregorian Dates and Vice Versa. I've run into a weird problem that I cannot find an answer for in my Julian to Gregorian code where non-leap years are calculating as leap years and leap years are calculating as non-leap years.

Exp: When I enter the JDE Julian Date '122095' it should return 04/05/2022 but instead returns 04/06/2022. When I changed the year to 2020, a leap year, it returned todays correct date of 04/05/2022 when it should have returned 04/04/2020.

I think the problem might be with my DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch converter because it is return 2022-04-06 06:00:00.000Z and I don't know where the 6 in the hour spot is coming from or how to cancel it out. My Code is below.

Edit: I forgot, I used the code originally from [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60282586/6524521) post.

Edit Edit: Okay that fixed the problem, I set "var millisecondsSinceEpoch = DateTime(convYear()).millisecondsSinceEpoch;" to "var millisecondsSinceEpoch = DateTime.utc(convYear()).millisecondsSinceEpoch;" and it was still giving me the wrong answer. I then thought to take the "isUtc: True" off of the end of "var dayOfYearDate = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch((millisecondsSinceEpoch + millisDayOfYear));" and that fixed the issue. The best I can figure is having the UTC bool at the end of that line was preventing millisecondsSinceEpoch from actually converting to UTC.

Thanks jamesdlin and James Heap for your help!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';


gregDate(var inputDate) {
  var inputDate = '122095';
  // Break down JDE date into individual pieces
  var currentYear = int.parse(DateFormat('yy').format(DateTime.now()));
  print('Current Year: $currentYear');
  var splitYear = int.parse(inputDate.substring(1, 3));
  print('Split Year: $splitYear');
  var splitDay = int.parse(inputDate.substring(3, inputDate.length));
  print('Split Day: $splitDay');

// Uses the current year to determine if our 2 digit date needs a 19 or 20 in the front
  convYear() {
    if (splitYear <= currentYear) {
      var year = '20' + splitYear.toString();
      return int.parse(year);
    }
    else {
      var year = '19' + splitYear.toString();
      return int.parse(year);
    }
  }
  print('Converted Year: ${convYear()}');
  

  // Takes 3 digit day in year and converts it to formatted date time.
  convDate() {
    var dayOfYear = splitDay;
    var millisInADay = Duration(days: 1).inMilliseconds; // 86400000
    print(millisInADay);
    var millisDayOfYear = dayOfYear * millisInADay;
    print(millisDayOfYear);
    var millisecondsSinceEpoch = DateTime.utc(convYear()).millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    print(millisecondsSinceEpoch);


    var dayOfYearDate = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch((millisecondsSinceEpoch + millisDayOfYear), isUtc: true);
    var result = DateFormat('MM/dd/${convYear()}').format(dayOfYearDate);

    print(dayOfYearDate);
    print(result);
    return result;
  }
  return convDate();

}
```

Comment: I don't know if it's the cause of your problem, but `DateTime(convYear())` creates a `DateTime` for January 1 of that year *in your local time zone*.  If you want your calculation to not depend on the time zone where you're running your code, you should use `DateTime.utc`.  Also, for questions like "I don't know where the 6 in the hour spot is coming from", it would help to know what your time zone is.

Comment: The 6 is coming from your offset to UTC - presumably you are in Colorado or equivalent timezone. Consider switching to working exclusively in UTC, using `DateTime.utc()` and/or adding `isUtc:true` to the `.from...Epoch` methods.

Comment: Is there a way to convert a three digit day of the year to month and day date with UTC? That is why I'm using the Epoch method, if there is an easier way then I'm all for it.